# Почему в цикле функция fwrite() корректно не работает? Если записать информацию в файл одним блоком, то все нормально?

Tags: c, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Изучая бинарные операции пытался "шифровать" информацию в файле. Не могу понять почему в цикле не получается записать по байтно информацию в файл использую fwrite(). Если все данные записать разом одним блоком, то все гуд.
При изучении этого вопроса в коде есть повторяющиеся блоки для контроля внутреннего указателя в файле. При выполнении отладки в пошаговом режиме программа корректно отрабатывает.

Ссылка на проект codeblocks
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZikyrwI2-5BWkIfuEjdMXSgNk6efwxGH?usp=sharing

Сам код. Файл binary.h и текстовый файл original.txt есть в проекте на Drive Google. Программа побайтно меняет данные в файле в соответствии с заданной маской и записывает обратно

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "binary.h" // !!!!!!
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

char chr; // шифруемый символ
char chr_secret; // зашифрованный символ
char mask = b01010101; // Маска для шифрования при помощи ^

// Шифрование
void coding(void)
{
    FILE * f_original;
    f_original = fopen("original.txt", "rb+");
    fseek(f_original, 0, SEEK_END);
    long flenght = ftell(f_original);
    fseek(f_original, 0, SEEK_SET);
    // Было так
    /*char * pchr;
    pchr = (char *) malloc(flenght * sizeof(int));

    int i = 0;
    while(fread(&chr, sizeof(chr), 1, f_original))
    {
        chr_secret = chr ^ mask;
        chr_secret = ~chr_secret;
        pchr[i++] = chr_secret;
    }

    fclose(f_original); f_original = fopen("original.txt", "wb+");
    fwrite(pchr, flenght, 1, f_original); // сразу записал строку целиком
    free(pchr); fclose(f_original);*/

    long my_long;
    while(fread(&chr, sizeof(chr), 1, f_original))
    {
        chr_secret = chr ^ mask;
        chr_secret = ~chr_secret;

        //одинаковые блоки. Использовал для просмотра внутреннего указателя
        /*{
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
            fseek(f_original, 0, SEEK_END);
            printf("%lu", ftell(f_original));
            fseek(f_original, my_long, SEEK_SET);
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
        }*/


        fseek(f_original, -1, SEEK_CUR);

        /*{
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
            fseek(f_original, 0, SEEK_END);
            printf("%lu", ftell(f_original));
            fseek(f_original, my_long, SEEK_SET);
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
        }*/

        fwrite(&chr_secret, sizeof(char), 1, f_original);

        // как только комментируешь последний блок программа уходит в ошибку
        // как будто процессор работает быстрее, запись в файл еще не успела произойти
        {
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
            fseek(f_original, 0, SEEK_END);
            printf("%lu", ftell(f_original));
            fseek(f_original, my_long, SEEK_SET);
            my_long = ftell(f_original);
            printf("%lu", my_long);
        }

    }
    fclose(f_original);
}

int main()
{
    coding();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте сброс на диск `fflush(f_original);`:

```
while(fread(&chr, sizeof(chr), 1, f_original))
{
    chr_secret = chr ^ mask;
    chr_secret = ~chr_secret;
    fseek(f_original, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&chr_secret, sizeof(char), 1, f_original);
    fflush(f_original);
}
fclose(f_original);
```

Так работает?

Но так будет явно медленнее, чем работать с блоками.

Comment: Да, с fflush() работает. Спасибо. Если я правильно понял, в моем коде данные копятся в буфер, а потом стразу отправляется и происходит проблема? fflush() не дается копить данные, а сразу отправляет, в данном случае каждый байт?

Comment: Ну, как версия :) Ваши прыжки по файлу навели на мысль о сбросе буферов при этом...